# How to get odd indexed values from a vector?

Tags: clojure

Suppose there's a vector of names:

```
(def noms ["Tim" "Joseph" "Steven" "Michael"])
```

How to get the names from odd-index ?

Update:
Actually, I was trying to rewrite this Rust code in Clojure:

```
fn main() {
    let nums = [1, 2];
    let noms = ["Tim", "Eston", "Aaron", "Ben"];

    let mut odds = nums.iter().map(|&x| x * 2 - 1);

    for num in odds {
        spawn(proc() {
            println!("{:s} says hello from a lightweight thread!", noms[num]);
        });
    }
}
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do it?

Edit:
Here is the Clojure code that did almost the same with the above mentioned Rust code:

```
(def  noms ["Tim", "Eston", "Aaron", "Ben"])
(doseq [i (take-nth 2 (rest noms))]
    (println i "says hello from a lightweight thread!"))
```

The new question is: How to write "lightweight" thread (or something equivalent in Clojure terms)?

Comment: `(keep-indexed #(if (odd? %1) %2) nums)`

Comment: Not so hot if `nums` contains `nil` entries in it.

Comment: It's better to post a new question rather than editing this one.

Comment: In general, don't explicitly print the result. The repl will print it if you return it.

Comment: Is this about concurrent processes or about filtering a collection? The problem posed is naturally serial.

Comment: @turingcomplete You're right. I'll mark this question as answered, and start a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `take-nth`

```
(take-nth 2 (rest ["Tim" "Joseph" "Steven" "Michael"]))
```

Comment: take-nth is the right answer to the original question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, here is one approach.

```
user=> v
[:a :b :c :d :e :f :g]
user=> (map #(v %) (filter odd? (range (count v))))
(:b :d :f)
user=>
```

There is probably a more elegant way to do this, but this one is pretty straight-forward and shold be reasonably clear.

I found it very useful to really focus on the map/filter/reduce patterns for clojure. I rarely need to use loop, for etc and moving away from those staples learnt in other languages took a bit of effort.

Comment: Could be (map #(v %) (range 1 (count v) 2)) instead.

Comment: @Tim X Your second paragraph is really useful --- it provides big idea in functional programming. Thank you.

Comment: @Nick High recommend reading the Joy of Clojure. While this book does cover the basics, it is excellent for the way it covers the more abstract ideas and concepts. Really helps to get your mindset right and has real substance that makes you think more deeply about the language

Comment: @TimX That's really a good book, I just get started to read it, and plan to read it at least two times. Good recommendation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use map-indexed and remove.

```
user> (def noms ["Tim" "Joseph" "Steven" "Michael"])
#'user/noms
user> (->> noms
           (map-indexed (fn [idx x]
                          (if (odd? idx) x)))
           (remove nil?))

;=> ("Joseph" "Michael")
```